# PHP MSSQL Distinct is not working

Tags: php, sql-server, select

I have three columns in a table **Id, State, City.** Each state contains dozens of cities. all I want to do is select unique states and get their Id.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(State) FROM LocationTable;
```

This works perfectly, but I need to get Id too. I tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(State), Id FROM LocationTable
```

And

```
SELECT State, Id FROM LocationTable GROUP BY State, Id
```

But it still doesn't return unique states.. Basically I need to get this MySQL query running on MSSQL:

```
SELECT UNIQUE(State), Id FROM LocationTable;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT State, Id FROM LocationTable GROUP BY State, Id
```

What do you expect it to do when it finds 2 states that match, but have different IDs? It would return the state twice, once per ID.

I suspect your data is something like this:

```
 ID, State, City
  1   WA    Seattle
  2   WA    Tacoma
```

When you say you want the ID for the state, you are going to have to make a choice about which ID would would want, max, min, etc. There is no single ID for the state.

Response to comment : It could be something like...

```
Select max(cast(id as binary(16)), state from locationtable group by state
```

But I think the validity of the ID is really in question here, what are you going to do with the ID, it will be for 1 row only, not all rows for that state. (Cast to now deal with the fact its a uniqueidentifier field)

Comment: Thanks, can you please show me SQL query how to do that in my case? I don't care which ID it gets, could be random.

Comment: Thanks. I use binary ID's, how can MAX be applied to them, I get Operand data type uniqueidentifier is invalid for max operator. T

Comment: Details like this should be in the original question, cast added.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Andrew's answer:

`DISTINCT` applies to the entire set of data, not just the column that comes after it.

```
SELECT distinct State, MAX(Id) 
FROM LocationTable 
GROUP BY state
```

Will give you the largest `Id` numerically. But, like Andrew said, you'll have to choose how you want to limit the `Id` that you're retrieving.

See this for a working example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f5b42/5

Comment: Not that its any harm, but you don't need a distinct with the group by in place.

Comment: Because you're using an aggregate function (`MAX`) you need a `GROUP BY`, no?

Comment: Yup, but the distinct clause is doing nothing because the group by is in place already doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Try distinct as a keyword, and not a function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT State,Id FROM LocationTable
```

Comment: @user1594313 - That's because the states have different IDs.  Different IDs == distinct records.  **You** need to determine if you want the smallest ID or the largest ID per state.